# Начало выполнения функции по таймеру бездействия

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть input - надо выполнить. Человек начинает вводить в это поле данные по `$('input').live('keyup',function(){})`, если он остановился на 1 секунду и более, то должна выполнятся функция... функция не должна начать выполнятся, если человек непрерывно вводит текст. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input').live('keyup', function(){
    if(window.a) clearTimeout(window.a);
    window.a = setTimeout(function(){
        //...
    }, 1000);
});
```

Можно еще по `clearTimeout(window.a)` отменить выполнение функции.

Comment: только метод не **.live()**, а **[.on()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On)**.