# Отложенный запуск функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая должна вызывается по изменению текстового поля. Так как она отправляет ajax-запрос, не хотелось бы чтобы она срабатывала после каждого изменения текстового поля.

Как можно сделать так чтобы функция срабатывала только в том случае если изменения не происходили некоторое время?

Comment: @Grundy хватит буянить, там jQuery

Comment: @andreymal, в чем принципиальная разница?

Comment: @Grundy в том, что jQuery половина народа не поймёт по причине незнания, например?

Comment: @andreymal, вопрос же не в навешивании события. а в работе с setTimeout

Comment: @Grundy формулировка этого вопроса подразумевает и навешивание события тоже, причём без jQuery, хватит буянить

Comment: @Grundy и тот вопрос сам по себе дубликат, раз на то пошло: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136878

Comment: @Bharata, нет,у него текст вопроса почти дословно повторяет текст дубликата

Comment: @Grundy, да, вы однозначно правы. Извините. не увидел это сразу. Свой предыдущий отзыв/предположение я удалил, дабы не вводить других в заблуждение.

Comment: @Grundy все хорошо, дубликат помог, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Суть такова: при вводе запускаем таймер, при повторном вводе — перезапускаем. Если никто ничего долго не вводит, то таймер никто не перезапускает, и в конце концов он сработает (минимум через секунду в данном примере)

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var info = document.getElementById('info');

// Храним здесь ID таймера, чтобы отменять при вводе
var task = null;

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    info.textContent = 'Скоро сработает таймер';
    // Если есть старый таймер, то отменяем его
    if (task !== null) {
        clearTimeout(task);
        task = null;
    }
    // Запускаем новый таймер
    task = setTimeout(someWork, 1000);
});

function someWork() {
    task = null;  // Таймер отработал, ID хранить больше не нужно
    info.textContent = 'Введено: ' + input.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Пиши в меня" />
<div id="info"></div>
```